# How Many HABTM relationships in cakephp is too many?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm struggling with deciding how many HABTM relationships I really need in my cakephp app.  I guess I don't quite get what "has" truly means.  I don't want to have more HABTM tables than necessary.  Here's what I have in my database:

```
Users
Properties
Leases
Payments
Repairs
```

`user` HABTM `properties`, `user` HABTM `leases`, `user` HABTM `users`, `user` HABTM `repairs`, `property` hasMany `repairs`, `property` hasMany `leases`, `lease` hasMany `repairs`.

Also, I have two aliases for my `users` model (`manager` and `tenant`).  This is one of the reasons I ended up with so many HABTM relationships, but I'm not sure it's necessary.

Do I have too many user HABTM relationships?  Would it be better to just have cake recurse through my models?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather subjective question. That is to say one only you can decide as you know your code. The best thing to do is ask yourself if the following is strictly true: *X really has and belongs to many Y*?

For example, does `User` really have many `Payment`? Or does `User` have a `Lease` and the `Lease` has `Payments`? Same with `Repairs` and `Properties`.

As far as CakePHP having *too many*, I wouldn't worry about that. Setting the `recursive` property on your `find()`, using `Containable`, or `un/bindModel()` will also help limit when all these relationships are used.

Comment: I have decided to eliminate the redundant relationships so now I am left with something that looks a lot cleaner.  Thanks!

Comment: One last thing: Right now I'm linking `managers` and `tenants` with a `managers_tenants` table.  But since `managers` HABTM `leases` and `tenants` HABTM `leases` would it be better to allow cakephp to link `managers` and `tenants` together through the common `leases` model?  I suppose this also depends on my code..

Comment: It does. But personally I would agree that these things should be done thru the `Lease` model. Really, the tricky part would be how to differential `Users` into `Managers` and `Tenants`.